# No connections available in the pool, Laravel and Redis

Tags: laravel-5, redis

I've setup a redis cluster with 6 nodes locally on my ubuntu 18.04, starting from 127.0.0.1:7000 to 127.0.0.1:7006, with the default 'utils/create-cluster' script that comes with redis binaries.

I'm having issues setting up redis on a laravel 5.7 application, I'm trying to make a request to an endpoint and I'm getting the following error

```
No connections available in the pool at line 337
myApp/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Aggregate/RedisCluster.php
```

It's exactly the same error from here --> [Predis with laravel 5.5 "No connections available in the pool in Aggregate/RedisCluster.php:337 "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673885/predis-with-laravel-5-5-no-connections-available-in-the-pool-in-aggregate-redis) 
But that answer has not solved my issue, nor the referred link --> https://github.com/nrk/predis/issues/480

My .env file has the following values

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null   
REDIS_PORT=7000
```

And my app/database.php is as follows

```
'redis' => [
    'client' => 'predis',
    'cluster' => true,
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis',
    ],
    'clusters' => [
        'default' => [
            [
                'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
            ],
        ],
        'cache' => [
            [
                'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
            ],
        ]
    ],
],
```

I'd appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of googling and trial and error, I managed to solve the problem by changing the file `config/cache.php` at the following lines

error:

```
'redis' => [
    'driver' => 'redis'
    'connection' => 'cache'
]
```

working:

```
'redis' => [
    'driver' => 'redis'
    'connection' => 'default'
]
```