# No connections available in the pool, Laravel predis

Tags: laravel, redis, amazon-elasticache, predis

I have the error "No connections available in the pool" under laravel 7, php7.4 and redis server on AWZ elasticache.

Here my .env :

```
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_SCHEME=tls
REDIS_HOST=clustercfg.xxx.xxx.xxx.cache.amazonaws.com
REDIS_PASSWORD=xxx
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

my config/database.php :

```
    'redis' => [
         'cluster' => true,
         'client' => 'predis',
         'options' => [
             'cluster' => 'redis',
             'parameters' => [
                 'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),
                 'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                 'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                 'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                 'database' => 0,
                 'timeout' => 15,
              ],
         ],

         'clusters' => [
             'default' => [
               [
                 'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),
                 'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                 'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                 'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                 'database' => 0,
                 'timeout' => 15,
               ]
             ],
             'cache' => [
               [
                 'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),
                 'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                 'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                 'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                 'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
               ]
             ],
         ],
     ],
```

clustercfg.xxx.xxx.xxx.cache.amazonaws.com is my configuration endpoint and REDIS_PASSWORD my AUTH token
[image]

I have basically copied the solution of [Predis with laravel 5.5 "No connections available in the pool in Aggregate/RedisCluster.php:337 "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673885/predis-with-laravel-5-5-no-connections-available-in-the-pool-in-aggregate-redis)

but problem is not resolved.

I have looked at the vpc security group in amazon and basically all ports are opened :
[image]

Comment: did you find a cause? i still have this error. Laravel cache is not working with Elasticache Redis Cluster.
But i can connect Elasticache redis with Redis-cli, don't know where wrong in config.

Comment: sorry, I didn't find a solution and kinda move on not implementing the session under redis for the time being.